# Email to Case question

Tags: email2case, case

I am hoping that someone can help me with this. I had this request today and I just have no idea if it is possible. Thanks in advance. (We use e2c premium)

If someone emails support@ourwork.com and has people on the cc or 
bcc line they will be added to the AditionalCC field in SF.  We need to 
stop this as the default behavior.  If people are on that line, they 
need to be stripped off.  We do need the ability to manually add people 
to the AdditionalCC field.  We also need the ability to have a group of 
people always added to that field for every case for a particular 
customer.

Example1: I'm working a case with Jill and she wants her boss to 
be cced on every case communication.

Example2: We have Company1 cases that are sent in from either Company1 or Partner1. 
We want two project managers at the Company1 and one at Partner1 
included on every case communication that is created, despite who 
actually created the case.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but I guess you can create a before trigger on the EmailMessage object and remove the values on the ccAddress field by default.

For the other question, you could have a field on the case that would store the list of addresses and based on that field being populated you would automatically pass that value on the URL when clicking on the send email button. For this you will need to use a custom button.

Bear in mind that only the send email button on the task is replaceable, the one in the email related list is not, which can be an issue. This can possibly be workarounded by using JavaScript somewhere on the page (like on the sidebar) that would do this automatically without using the custom button. I hope it helps.